# Return a value from accessSync other than ENOENT

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

How would I return `false` from `accessSync` when it fails to find a file/dir instead of `ENOENT`?

**unit test**

```
it.only('should be able to read a file stream only if a file exist', function() {
    let testfile = testpath+'/imageeee.png';
    let ok = FileService.existsAsync(testfile);

    ok = ok.then((result) => {
      console.log('exists: ', result);
      return FileService.createReadStream(testfile);
    });

    ok = ok.then((result) => {
      assert.isNotNull(result.path);
      assert.equal(result.path, testfile);
      assert.isTrue(result.readable, true);
    });
    return ok;
  });
```

**function**

```
 existsAsync(path) {
    let ok = fs.accessAsync(path, fs.F_OK);
    ok = ok.then(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return ok;
  },
```

**error**

```
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/home/j/Work/imageeee.png'
```

Answer (score -1):

Anything that throws an error can be wrapped in a try...catch block to capture the error and proceed from there. If this is the problem function here:

```
fs.accessAsync(path, fs.F_OK);
```

Wrap it in a try catch and return false in the error case:

```
try {
    fs.accessAsync(path, fs.F_OK);
    // ... other code
    return true;
} catch(e) {
    // log the error ?
    return false;
}
```

Comment: that does not work in this case because it is not promisified. the error returned from this code is  `ok.then is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

Consider this as an alternative solution to avoid the ENOENT error by using 'child_process' with cat instead of the 'fs' capabilities to know if a file exists or not (with an actual catch error exception working without interfere with your main current process).

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function is_file(path){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
      exec(`cat ${path}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => { // cat required
        if (err) {
          resolve(false);
        } else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
    } catch ( e ) { resolve(false); }
  });
}

async function main(){
  let file = `foo.txt`;
  if ( (await is_file(file)) ) {
    console.log(`file exists: ${file}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`no such file: ${file}`);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score -2):

the solution is to:

1) Promisify the method that calls accessAsync

2) `resolve` the error if there is one instead of rejecting it

This will still return the error if the result is `false` but it will not break the promise chain. In order to return `false` you can simply do `resolve(false)` but I found it more useful to actual return the error and handle it in my test.

**modified code:**

```
existsAsync(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return fs.accessAsync(path, fs.F_OK, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          resolve(err);
        } else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      });   
    });
  },
```